# How can I display these from my arraylist?

Tags: c#

This is my main class.

I am basing it off another example i had done before and it works jsut fine the same way, this is my first time using an arraylist so maybe it's something to do with that I'm not sure. I just need it to display and the arraylist to work properly I think everything else works fine.

Right now I am getting an error on:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-12} {2,-12} {3,-12} {4,-12} {5,-12} {6,-12}",
    plan[idx].GetCardNumber(), plan[idx].GetCreditBalance(), plan[idx].GetMonthlyPayment(),
    plan[idx].GetAnnualRate(), plan[idx].MonthsToPayOff(), plan[idx].TotalPayment(),
    plan[idx].CompanyProfit());
```

saying that:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for ___ eg( .getcreditbalance

full program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;


namespace Assignment1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList plan = new ArrayList();
            int count = 0;
            char option;

            Console.WriteLine("--= Credit Card Calculator =-- ");
            Console.WriteLine();

            do
            {
                option = ReadMenuOption();
                switch (option)
                {
                    case 'E':
                        count = count + 1;
                        AddPaymentPlan(count, plan);

                        break;
                    case 'V':
                        Display(count, plan);
                        break;
                    case 'X':
                        Console.WriteLine("Goodybye.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid option.");
                        break;
                }

            } while (option != 'X');
        }


        static char ReadMenuOption()
        {
            char option;

            Console.WriteLine("Options Menu");
            Console.WriteLine("====================");
            Console.WriteLine("E - Enter calculation information");
            Console.WriteLine("V - View calculation report");
            Console.WriteLine("X - Exit");
            option = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()[0];

            return option;
        }

        static void Display(int count, ArrayList plan)
        {
            if (count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There are no values to show!");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int idx = 0; idx < plan.Count; idx = idx + 1)
                {


                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-12}  {1,-12}  {2,-12}  {3,-12}  {4,-12}  {5,12}  {6,-12}", " Card Number", "Card Balance", "Monthly Payment", "APR", "Months to Pay", "Total Payment", "Company Profit");

                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-12}   {1,-12}  {2,-12}   {3,-12}   {4,-12}   {5,-12}   {6,-12}", plan[idx].GetCardNumber(), plan[idx].GetCreditBalance(), plan[idx].GetMonthlyPayment(), plan[idx].GetAnnualRate(), plan[idx].MonthsToPayOff(), plan[idx].TotalPayment(), plan[idx].CompanyProfit());
                }

            }
        }

        static int AddPaymentPlan(int count, ArrayList plan)


        {
            PaymentPlan p = new PaymentPlan();

                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter card number: ");
                        p.SetCardNumber(long.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));


                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid card number");
                    }
                } while (p.GetCardNumber().Equals(""));

                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter card balance: ");
                        p.SetCreditBalance(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid card balance.");
                    }
                } while (p.GetCreditBalance().Equals(""));


                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter payment amount: ");
                        p.SetMonthlyPayment(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid payment amount.");
                    }
                } while (p.GetMonthlyPayment().Equals(""));



                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter annual rate: ");
                        p.SetAnnualRate(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
                    }
                } while (p.GetAnnualRate().Equals(""));

                plan.Add(p);

                Console.WriteLine("It will take {0} months to pay off your credit card", p.MonthsToPayOff());
                Console.WriteLine();


            count = count + 1;
            return count;



        }
    }
}










and my Payment plan class :


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment1
{
    class PaymentPlan
    {
        private long _cardNumber;
        private double _creditBalance;
        private double _monthlyPayment;
        private double _annualRate;

        public PaymentPlan()
        {
            _cardNumber = 0;
            _creditBalance = 0;
            _monthlyPayment = 0;
            _annualRate = 0;
        }

        public PaymentPlan(long cardNumber, double creditBalance, double monthlyPayment, double annualRate)
        {
            SetCardNumber(cardNumber);
            SetCreditBalance(creditBalance);
            SetMonthlyPayment(monthlyPayment);
            SetAnnualRate(annualRate);
        }

        public long GetCardNumber()
        {
            return _cardNumber;
        }

        public void SetCardNumber(long cardNumber)
        {
            if (cardNumber < 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Has to be a positive number");
            }
            _cardNumber = cardNumber;
        }

        public double GetCreditBalance()
        {
            return _creditBalance;
        }

        public void SetCreditBalance(double creditBalance)
        {
            if (creditBalance < 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Has to be a positive number");
            }
            _creditBalance = creditBalance;
        }

        public double GetMonthlyPayment()
        {
            return _monthlyPayment;
        }

        public void SetMonthlyPayment(double monthlyPayment)
        {
            if (monthlyPayment < 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Has to be a positive number");
            }
            _monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment;
        }
        public double GetAnnualRate()
        {
            return _annualRate;
        }

        public void SetAnnualRate(double annualRate)
        {
            if (annualRate < 0 || annualRate > 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Has to be a positive number between 0.0 & 1.0");
            }
            _annualRate = annualRate;
        }

        public double MonthsToPayOff()
        {
            double months;
            double daily;
            double monthly;
            double tinycalc;
            double innerbrac;
            double bottom;
            double upperbrac;

            daily = _annualRate / 365;

            //calculates number of months to be returned to main and displayed for user
            monthly = _creditBalance / _monthlyPayment;
            tinycalc = -1.0 / 30;
            innerbrac = Math.Pow(1 + daily, 30);
            bottom = Math.Log(1 + daily);
            upperbrac = Math.Log(1 + (_monthlyPayment * (1 - innerbrac)));

            months = Math.Round(tinycalc * (upperbrac / bottom));

            return months;
        }

        public double TotalPayment()
        {
            return GetCreditBalance() * (MonthsToPayOff() * GetMonthlyPayment());
        }

        public double CompanyProfit()
        {

            return TotalPayment() - _creditBalance;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Right now I am getting an error on Console.WriteLine("{0,-12}   {1,-12}  {2,-12}   {3,-12}   {4,-12}   {5,-12}   {6,-12}", plan[idx].GetCardNumber(), plan[idx].GetCreditBalance(), plan[idx].GetMonthlyPayment(), plan[idx].GetAnnualRate(), plan[idx].MonthsToPayOff(), plan[idx].TotalPayment(), plan[idx].CompanyProfit());

Comment: saying that 'object' does not contain a definition for ___ eg( .getcreditbalance

Comment: You really want List<PaymentPlan>

Answer (score 3):

An `ArrayList` is an outdated way of storing a collection.

Every item is stored as an `object`, and until you cast the item back to the original type, you can't access any properties or methods on the original type.

```
((PaymentPlan)plan[idx]).GetCardNumber()
```

Better yet, replace the `ArrayList` with a `List<PaymentPlan>`. The `List<T>` construct is type-safe, so you don't have to recall the original type and cast items each time you want to access use them.

```
var plans = new List<PaymentPlan>();
plans.Add(new PaymentPlan(12345, ...));
Console.WriteLine(plans[idx].GetCardNumber());
```

Comment: Yes, C# does not know what the type is in ArrayList -- you have to tell it.

Comment: ah awesome that works perfectly. one last thing, my MonthsToPay, total profit and company profit just display as NaN

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to use the break point. I know how to add one but not use it. I'm thinking it must be in how i have the calculations set up in the paymenplan class